# MSDeploy get error during upload big file to IIS server

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msdeploy

I get following error, when I try to deploy a web app to IIS server using MSDeploy. I believe the cause of the issue is the size of the file. The file, which cause the problem, is the biggest file in the package with size 8M. May I know how to deal with it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We had this same error a while back and it was a network issue.  Pulled in our Network Operations team and they ran a diagnostic test and found the issue.  Not sure what it was but I bet this is the same.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Could you get more detail of the cause?

Comment: Sorry, the network guys figured it out and I didn't get those details.

Comment: Thank U! Chief7, your hint lead us find the cause of the issue. The firewall block the traffic, since it thought the traffic is an attack. LoL

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please vote it up or mark it as the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by firewall rules. Our network team found the traffic from the deployment server to IIS server was treated as an attack by firewall, then lock the traffic. After they make an exception between those two servers, the issue be resolved. Thanks again Chief7